# Windows 7 breadcrumbs in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, windows-7, breadcrumbs

I could have swore I have seen this before, but has anyone the Windows 7 breadcrumb feature done in jQuery?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing out on something, but what exactly is the 'breadcrumb feature'? A quick Google search appears to refer to the directory location path in the window navigation bar. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Please clarify what the windows7 breadcrump feature is.

Comment: Is there something special about breadcrumbs in Windows 7, or are you just looking for a jQuery breadcrumb plugin?

Comment: What is "Windows 7 breadcrumb feature" ?

Comment: The Windows 7 breadcrumb is a very clever design, it enables users to navigate any depth folder with ease and cleverly collpases the information that doesnt fit in your screen. You really have to use it to get a feel for all of its features

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an article](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/10/breadcrum-menu-using-jquery-and-aspnet.html) on jQuery breadcrumbs that are similar to the Vista/Windows 7 style. It's for ASP.NET MVC but includes the javascript that could be used elsewhere.

Comment: I've seen this one before, and oddly enough this will be for an ASP.NET project - but I am fairly certain there was one that attempted to mimic the functionality near perfectly.

I appreciate the response though.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [xbreadcrumbs](http://www.ajaxblender.com/xbreadcrumbs.html) and jBreadCrumb might be interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old... but if it can still be helpful, I developed a jQuery plugin which collapses the breadcrumbs elements depending on the available space in the browser window (as explained in the [Blowsie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370286/blowsie)'s comment).

So, it works the same way the Windows breadcrumbs does. At least for this feature. The plugin doesn't have drop down menu.

Here is the link : [jquery-rcrumbs](https://github.com/cm0s/jquery-rcrumbs)